# Report Builder 3.0, breaking out data field for Bar Chart

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm using Report Builder 3.0 and trying to figure out if i can break out one datafield with the few values I need for my bar chart.  The data looks like this;

[[44278,47411],[{"name":"$41,000/year goal","y":41000}],["",""]]

I want bar 1 to be the 44,278 value, bar 2 to be the 47,411 value and the 41000 to be embedded as a goal.  I've attached a screenshot of how we have it working with other grid and charting products, but this is going to be embedded in a much more in-depth SSRS report. Any sort of help would be great as i'm new to the whole SSRS reporting system.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a custom StripLine:

- Right-click the vertical chart axis and click Vertical Axis Properties.
- The axis properties are displayed in the Properties window.
- In the Appearance section of the Properties pane, for the StripLines property, click the Edit Collection (…) button to open the ChartStripLine Collection Editor.
- Click Add to add a new strip line to the collection.
- Click StripWidth to specify the width of the strip line. If your goals will fluctuate, you might want to make it relative to your Goal e.g. `=Fields!YourGoalField.Value/100`
- Set the StripWidthType property to Number.
- Set the InvervalOffset value to `=Fields!YourGoalField.Value`.
- Set the IntervalOffsetType value to Number.

More on StripeLines: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239316.aspx

**EDIT** To get the Goal Label outside the Chart Area as depicted, we have to do a sort of hack:

- Delete the StripLine Title as there is no way to get that outside the Chart Area.
- Right Click the Chart and select `Add New Title`.
- On your new Chart Title's Properties Pane

  - Set the `Docking Position` to `Right Center`.
  - Set the `TextOrientation` to `Horizontal`.
  - Adjust the Font style and color to match your spec.
  - Set the `Caption Expression` to `=Format(Fields!YourGoal.Value,"$0,000") & "/year goal"`

Here is where the hack comes in. In order to get the Goal label to line up with the Goal Line, you need to add a certain number of carriage return/line feeds to your `Caption Expression`. To do this, append `& vbcrlf` to the `Caption Expression` a bunch of times and keep testing until it lines up. You might also want to adjust the `DockingOffset` property to move the Label closer to the Chart Area.

Comment: this worked excellent! Thank you for the suggestion and in-depth description how to do this.  One question i had was if you knew any way to get my stripLine title to be outside the chart area like it is above, just aligned to the right.  I have tried the Right property in titleAlign for striplines stuff but that just goes to the exact width of the chart. Thanks again!

Comment: You are quite welcome! Happy to help. :) I have updated the answer to include how to get the Goal Label outside the Chart Area.

Comment: Thanks again for going through that, unfortunately i don't think that's going to work for me as these will end up being dynamic and their location might vary, so i might have to find a different workaround.  One other thing i was trying to look into was if stripLines can be over the top of the data columns?  everything i've read says no, but i thought i'd ask you as you seem to be pretty fluent in Report Builder.  thanks agian!

Comment: Sorry, I don't think so.